# Is there a way to inject specific options within an installer package in bash on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: bash, ubuntu-18.04

Recently I've been working on a bash script which would download a specific installer program and run it.  However, when you run the installer program it has specific questions that it asks and you have to manually choose the options.

My question is if there's a way that I can add the options for the installer within bash and then have it choose those options when the installer runs.

If there's no way to inject these options from bash while the program is running, then what would be a good way (programmatically) to accomplish this within Ubuntu 18.04?

Any ideas would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: I suggest to take a look at [expect](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/expect/info).

Comment: Thank you Cyrus for the recommendation.  I'll look into it more and the "autoexpect" options associated with it.